# What would happen if stock markets were open 24 hours?

Tags: stock-market, markets

Suppose you are a broker or a trader, and the stock markets will be open 24 hours a day.

What would be the implication for you as a broker in this scenario? 
I mean:

- How will your strategies change?
- Will it be more difficult or easier to trade?
- What algorithms that you know that would have to be adjusted in this scenario?

Comment: This is a valid question but in its current form it is incredibly broad. Perhaps narrow it down and if necessary post parts as separate questions.

Comment: @denesp i agree but i should add that a am a complete rookie in economy ,  i now basic facts but i lack of a lot understanding especially the terms. So i don't know how to narrow the question.

Comment: @denesp on the other hand, I'm afraid narrowing down the question would involve a bias on the answers.

Comment: @VicAche I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: @denesp I believe some concievable changes may hapen to unexpected aspect of trading, and spliting may cause us to miss one or the other

Comment: all this has historical context and a colonial construct has been replicated by nations all over the globe, in fact, the whole thing about market closing especially in Asian exchanges before 4 pm, too, is of sorts a colonial or more like a commonwealth thing. Nevertheless, it is an objective decision. Have found one podcast that is global as well as Indian stock market-centric, which has explained everything about this in detail, yet in under 15 minutes. Attaching the [link](https://open.spotify.com/episode/15l142L4i0DxisTBnNrjl1?si=2f00d3758eb04bf5).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have trading teams who work shifts like any other 24-hour business areas.

The power market is open 24-7; many companies have around-the-clock trading teams. A lot of analysis and other work that can be done in the daytime is still done in the daytime.

A major source of income during nighttime - in the power market - is just being there and executing trades - when other people are not there. I think that is the main change, that liquidity would shrink and give more arbitrage opportunities.

Answer (score 1):

Large investment firms already operate 24 hours a day in many cases, because they trade in different exchanges around the world that operate in different time zones. So from a practical standpoint, all that would change if individual exchanges went to a 24 hour schedule would be an increase in such activity. You’d also see less market movement at the opening of an exchange, since news coming in overnight (while exchanges are currently closed for trading) could be acted upon immediately.